# Dynamically show/hide subset of records?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am writing a web app using PHP, MySQL, jQuery, and some miscellaneous add-ons like jEditable and DataTables.  On most pages, the user will submit a form which will query the DB and bring back records matching my query rules.  This works for 95% of my users 95% of the time.  It's the other 5%/%% I am trying to help.

I am excluding records that are no longer being processed (completed/cancelled/accepted/rejected/etc.), leaving only "live" records. However, sometimes the leadership team needs to see the records I exclude.  I could write a whole other page or report for each case, but that seems a huge waste of time.

Is there a way to add a "show all records" checkbox or button to my page? When clicked, the button would get and display the rest of the data, so users don't have to refresh/go to another page/etc.

Comment: Without seeing how you'r excluding the `(completed/cancelled/accepted/rejected/etc)` within your MySQL query it's difficult to provide guidance. Can we see the existing query?

Comment: yeah give us pseudo code or something. Because it is more of a concept than syntax issue

Comment: I would add a filter for status, and default it to the 'live' status.  You can optionally change your query so that it limits the records by the choice selected in the filter (I'd recommend this approach if there are a lot of records in 'not live' statuses.  If you want more a more detailed answer, please provide your code.  See here for a generic example:  https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customFilters.html

Answer (score 0):

you should add a toggle switch - it could be just a check box, or you could use something fancy like this: http://simontabor.com/labs/toggles/

Bind an event to it that preforms a table.ajax.reload() in datatables to pull in the new records. Also, for the datatables ajax request, provide a callback that returns the toggled state of the toggle control as a post variable, then handle the filtering in your sql on the back end.

Note, this solution means you will have to configure datatables to source data via ajax, which, from what you described sounds like you should be doing anyway.